# Diferença entre uma master page e web form

Tags: vb.net, webforms

Gostaria de saber quais são as diferenças entre uma master page e uma web form, pois necessito de criar uma página web e quero saber qual é a mais aconselhada!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MasterPage como o próprio nome diz é uma pagina Master, utilizada como base para demais WebForms, por exemplo, você pode criar WebForms com ou sem master page, caso você selecione com MasterPage o novo WebForm será parte do Content da Master.
Normalmente é utilizado em casos onde você tem uma página padrão com cabeçalho ou outros itens e adiciona os WebForms utilizando sua MasterPage.
Essa imagem esclarece o que eu comentei acima:
O ContentPage é o seu WebForm e a MasterPage você consegue adicionar o seu WebForm como content nela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sendo que irei ter de realizar um formulário qual é a mais aconselhada?

Comment: Se é algo simples vai webform normal sem masterpage, agora se você necessita um layout como na imagem acima com header padrão, footer e etc crie uma MAsterPage pro seu projeto e utilize como citado acima.. Agora imagine que no seu formulário o cabeçalho você precise em outros formulários também, então crie uma MasterPage com o cabeçalho e crie os WebForms usando essa MasterPage, você não precisará ficar criando toda vez os componentes para os demais forms.

Comment: ok obrigado Thiago